# battlefield 4 dlc region compatability on ps4

Tags: battlefield-4, ps4

My bf4 is Asian region but my dlc is European region so it just says waiting to install, I was wondering if I could just borrow a European version disk, install it, the dlc then installs and then i just play with my Asian region disk?

Comment: Don't think that's possible, since that way it would be too easy to circumvent regioin locks.

Comment: This could also depend on the country you live in. The local gaming press here wrote that the China Rising DLC is not approved in China due it had the potential to raise riots or something.